# Column Deletion from Apache Druid

Tags: apache, druid

> How can we delete a column from druid datasource ?
>
> > I removed it from the datasource spec but still i can see it in the datasource.

Please assist if anyone is familiar with this.

Answer (score 2):

Druid is not like a conventional database where you define a structure, and that the structure is applied for all the data.

The data is stored in segments. Each segment contains the data which was put in this segment, together with the "structure" of that segment.

So, changing it in your dataSource spec will make sure that newly created segments will not include that new column. However, existing segments will still contain the column.

To remove this column, you need to re-index the older segments. During this re-index task, you can read the data from your existing segments and apply your new dataSource spec to it. You can then write it to the same segment where you have read it from.

See this link to read data from existing data sources:
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/native-batch.html#druid-input-source

In the latest version of druid (0.17.0) this is changed. It previously was done by an IngestSegmentFirehose.

Please make sure that you process the WHOLE segment. If you only overwrite a part of the segment, all the other data will be lost (at least, in the new version of your data).

Also note: After applying the rewrite, druid will put your new data in a newer version. However, your "old" version still exists. If you are not aware of this, your data storage can grow very quickly.

If you are happy with your result, you should execute a KILL task. This will delete all data (from older versions) which are no longer the "active" version.

If you are an PHP user, you can take a look at this package: https://github.com/level23/druid-client

We have implemented these re-index tasks together with easy querying in a class. Maybe it helps.

Comment: From the link that you mentioned above what i understood is to create a new segment if i want limited dimensions from the previous segments and then in the spec of new segment i should add the input source specifying the older segment and only the dimensions that i need to use. Is that correct ?